# Fineuploader fail with large size file and IE 11

Tags: fine-uploader

Good Day!

File upload is working fine with Chrome with all size of files.

Upload fails only with IE11 and file size larger than 5 MB.

Console Log

```
[FineUploader] Processing 1 files or inputs...
[FineUploader] Sending upload request for 0
[FineUploader] xhr - server response received for 0
[FineUploader] responseText = 
[FineUploader] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (SyntaxError: Syntax error)
```

Response Alert `(XHR returned response code 500)`, response fail only with Internet Explorer and large size file. For small size of files working fine with all browsers

Comment: What is the exact text of the response from your server?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no response!

Comment: Then you will need to look at your server logs to determine why your server is responding with a 500.

Comment: Thanks everyone but the issue is not resolved. I got following error on server.

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 13325368 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer:

But Memory allocation is 128M
memory_limit = 128M

Please let me know what could not the reason for this?